# Math program Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling to implement a program that prompts the user for an arithmetic expression,
**(for example; *1 + 1*)** and then calculates and outputs the result as a floating-point value formatted to one decimal place (**for example; *2.0***).

Also, I want there to be a space between x and y, and a space between y and z in the equation **(for example; *1 + 1*, with spaces between each character)**.

This is basically my desired output (in a terminal):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LuRH.png

I'm pretty new to python so this will probably seem easier to more experienced coders, but anyone have any ideas, and thanks in advance.

Comment: How does this code relate to the problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of `float()` around the expression parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply use `eval` directly on the expression inserted...

```
expression = str(input('Expression: '))
print("{:.1f}".format(eval(expression), 1))
```

output:

```
Expression: 1 + 1
2.0
```

Comment: using `eval` is bad practice, if you deliver this as the homework problem solution it will be rejected